# While loop in python(newbie)

Tags: python

hi am a newbie to python and i am having a bit of hard time understanding this simple while loop.this program is supposed to calculate the time its takes for the bacteria to double.

```
time = 0
population = 1000 # 1000 bacteria to start with 
growth_rate = 0.21 # 21% growth per minute
while population < 2000:
    population = population + growth_rate * population 
    print population
    time = time + 1
print "It took %d minutes for the bacteria to double." % time
print "...and the final population was %6.2f bacteria." % population
```

and the result is:

```
1210.0
1464.1
1771.561
2143.58881

It took 4 minutes for the bacteria to double.
...and the final population was 2143.59 bacteria.
```

what i dont get is why is the final result greater than 2000 cause its supposed to stop before 2000.i am i getting something wrong?

Comment: It stops looping once `population` is >= 2000. The final iteration is making it greater than 2000, ie 2143

Comment: It's funny that you can have splitted bacteria in your results ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads: "As long as the population is less than 2000, calculate the population of the next generation and then check again". Hence, it will always calculate one generation too many.

Try this:

```
while True:
   nextGen = population + growth_rate * population
   if nextGen > 2000: break
   population = nextGen
   print population
   time = time + 1
```

EDIT:

Or to get the exact result:

```
print (math.log (2) / math.log (1 + growth_rate) )
```

So the whole program could be:

```
import math

population = 1000
growth_rate = 0.21 # 21% growth per minute
t = math.log (2) / math.log (1 + growth_rate)
print 'It took {} minutes for the bacteria to double.'.format (t)
print '...and the final population was {} bacteria.'.format (2 * population)
```

Comment: Aren't you doing the exact same with your code, just in a worse coding style? Your code reads: "Calculate the population of the next generation forever, unless the population is greater or equal to 2000".

Comment: @Ben: No, that wouldn't produce the correct result either. It would give you the population of the generation **before** the one that had a population of more than 2000.

Comment: All of you absolutely correct. It is too early. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @jazzpi, it would give what the OP suggested they were having problems with. It wouldn't give the "correct" result, you'd have to go into fractions for that.

Comment: @Ben: "this program is supposed to calculate the time its takes for the bacteria to double." To really get to the correct equation, you'd need to go into logarithms, and not use while loops at all.

Comment: @Ben I suppose the thing OP is wondering about is why the loop runs one iteration too many, and not how to express his growth as a function over time.

Comment: Yes, I got that Hyperboreus... as I said the suggestion I made no your answer would _" give what the OP suggested they were having problems with"_, but not the "correct" answer... Did you mean to ping jazzpi?

Comment: @Ben, yes it was (at)jazzpi

Answer (score 1):

Because prior to your last iteration (#4 below) it IS below 2,000.
Iteration #1: 1210.0
Iteration #2: 1464.1
Iteration #3: 1771.561
Iteration #4: 2143.58881

Another way to do this, although perhaps less elegant, would be to add a break in your While loop like this (assuming all you care about is not printing any number higher than 2,000):

```
while population < 2000:
    population = population + growth_rate * population
    if population >= 2000:
        break
    else:
        print population
        time = time + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

At the penultimate iteration of the loop the population was less than 2,000, so there was another iteration. On the final iteration the population became more than 2,000 and so the loop exited.

If the population increased by 1 each time then you're correct; the loop would have exited at 2,000. You can see this behaviour using a simpler version:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    print i
```

Vary the amount that `i` increases by in order to see how it changes.

Comment: Thanks for giving an example that uses the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop is an example of an "entry controlled" loop. This means that the condition is checked before entering the loop. Hence, this means if your loop condition was violated during the previous iteration, but not at the beginning, your loop will terminate *after* the first violation, not before it.

Here is a simple example:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> while a < 5:
...     a = a+3
...     print a
... 
4
7
```

So, if you want that your loop must exit before a is greater than or equal to 5, you must do the check in the loop itself and break out of the loop:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> while a < 5:
...     a = a+3
...     if a < 5:
...             print a
...     else:
...             break
... 
4
```

Answer (score 0):

So your code right here:

```
while population < 2000:
    population = population + growth_rate*population
```

Say we enter that while loop and population = 1800, and growth_rate = .21. This satisfies all the requirements for the while loop to enter another loop. But, in the next line, you will set population = 1800 +(.21)*1800 which equals 2178. So, when you print out population, it will say 2178 even though it's higher than 2000

What you could do, is something like this:

```
while population < 2000:
    if population == population + growth_rate * population < 2000:
        population = population + growth_rate * population 
        time = time + 1
    else:
        break
    print population
```

Comment: You can't put a `=` sign into an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
time = 0
population = 1000 # 1000 bacteria to start with 
growth_rate = 0.21 # 21% growth per minute
while population != 2*population:
    population = population + (growth_rate * population )
    time = time + 1
print "It took %d minutes for the bacteria to double." % time
```

I think you will be getting the right output now.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a simple math problem - you're expecting the time to be an integer, although it probably is a floating point number. The loop can't stop when the population has reached 2000, because the way you're calculating it, it never has a value of 2000.

Comment: `while population < 2000:` will work just fine if population is a float. The "problem" is that the final iteration will bump the population over 2000.